# JS/jQuery Function meant to repeat triggers only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to make a simple banner rotator in JS&jQuery. I want it to go in cycles, but the problem is it triggers immediately only after the page load and not ever since.

Here is my code:

```
var stop = false;
var tar = 1;

function slide(){
    if(!stop){
        switch(tar){
            case 1:
            jQuery("#um1").toggle(300, function(){jQuery("#um2").toggle(300);});
            tar=2;
            break;
            case 2:
            jQuery("#um2").toggle(300, function(){jQuery("#um3").toggle(300);});
            tar=3;
            break;
            case 3:
            jQuery("#um3").toggle(300, function(){jQuery("#um1").toggle(300);});
            tar=1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#logosect").mouseenter(function(){ stop=true; });
    jQuery("#logosect").mouseleave(function(){ stop=false; });

    window.setInterval(slide(), 5000);
});
```

Comment: any errors in your console after the first run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference to [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), in your case the `slide()` is invoked when you are calling setInterval() and is passing the value returned by it(in this case undefined) as the callback to setInterval

```
window.setInterval(slide, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend clearInterval for performans issues. This should work for you.

```
var tar = 1;
var slideInterval;

function slide(){
        switch(tar){
            case 1:
            jQuery("#um1").toggle(300, function(){jQuery("#um2").toggle(300);});
            tar=2;
            break;
            case 2:
            jQuery("#um2").toggle(300, function(){jQuery("#um3").toggle(300);});
            tar=3;
            break;
            case 3:
            jQuery("#um3").toggle(300, function(){jQuery("#um1").toggle(300);});
            tar=1;
            break;
        }
}

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#logosect").mouseenter(function(){ 

         clearInterval( slideInterval );

    }).mouseleave(function(){ 

        slideInterval = window.setInterval(slide, 5000);

    }).trigger("mouseleave");


});
```